# Object Orientation

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have a project on object orientation due in a couple of weeks and Im completely aware that this is 'homework' per-say. Im just really stuck with these errors and I cant understand them at all! The errors im getting are saying that I dont have a while loop, illegal start of expression and reached end of file while parsing. I would really appreciate if you guys could help me out a little! Thanks!!

Here's my code so far:

{

```
public static void main(String[] args)

{   
    int choice;
    int index;
    String name = " ";
    int goals;
    int points;
    int noofthings;
    int location;
    Footballer tempObject;
    String search = "";
    int step;

    noofthings = 0;

    do{
            choice = menu();

            switch(choice)
        {
                    case 1 :
                {
                    step = 0;
                    System.out.print("Enter a name ");
                    name = EasyIn.getString();

                    while((step < noofthings) && !(names[step].getName().equals(name)))
                        {
                            step++;
                        }
                    if(step < noofthings)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Name already exists, choose another ");
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Enter amount of goals ");
                            goals = EasyIn.getInt();
                            System.out.println("Enter amount of points ");
                            points = EasyIn.getInt();
                            tempObject = new Footballer(name, goals, points);
                            location = findPlace(names, tempObject, noofthings);
                            noofthings = addOne(names, location, tempObject, noofthings);
                        }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is the Footballer class:

class Footballer
{

```
private String name;
private int goals;
private int points;


public Footballer () // constructor

{

}

public Footballer (String theName, int theGoals, int thePoints) // constructor

{
    name = theName;
    goals = theGoals;
    points = thePoints; 
}

// Mutators (Setter Methods)

public void setName (String theName)

{
    name = theName;
}

public void setGoals (int theGoals)

{
    goals = theGoals;
}

public void setPoints (int thePoints)

{
    points = thePoints;
}


// Selectors (Getter Methods) no parameters

public String getName ()

{
    return name;
}

public int getGoals()

{
    return goals;
}

public int getPoints ()

{
    return points;
}


public String toString ()

{
    String myString;

    myString = "";
    myString += "\n Name            : " + name;
    myString += "\n Goals Scored    : " + goals;
    myString += "\n Points Scored   : " + points;
    myString += "\n Total Points    : " + totalPoints() + "\n"; //prints the total points scored using the method totalPoints()

    return myString;

} 

//method to calculate the total points for a player
public int totalPoints()

{
    return goals * 3  + points;
}
```

}

This is the question: (might make it a bit easier)

****Player Ranking System – Array of Objects

In this project you are required to write a program that has 3 menu options
1.  Add Player
2.  Delete Player
3.  List All Players
4.  Exit
To do this you are required to use the Footballer Class stored on your common drive as Footballer.java. You are also required to copy the file FootballerUse14.java and modify it and submit it as your project file by storing it on your M drive. If your file is not saved as FootballerUse14.java it will not be collected and therefore will not get a mark. NOTE - YOU CANNOT CHAGE THE FOOTBALLER CLASS IN ANY WAY.
In the program you are required to write methods addone() deleteOne() findPlace() and listAll() etc. Footballer objects are to be added to an array of Footballer objects based on the value calculated by calling the totalPoints method in descending order, i.e. the Footballer with the highest total points will appear first in the array (i.e. at index position zero). When adding a Footballer object to the array the user is first asked for the Footballer name, if it exists already the program doesn’t allow you to add the Footballer but rather gives you a message indicating “Sorry this Footballer name exists already”. If it doesn’t exist already then the user is allowed to go ahead and enter the rest of the data. Similarly, when deleting a Footballer object from the array the program should ask you for the Footballer name, if it exists it is deleted, if not your program outputs to the user that the Footballer doesn’t exist.

---

Comment: What errors do you have?

Comment: What errors? (edit: ninja'd by 8 seconds)

Comment: Please post any stacktrace(s), and the rest of your relevant code. `menu()`? Also, please indent.

Comment: post Footballer and EasyIn classes

Comment: First thing I noticed, you have a `do` statement without a `while`

Comment: It's okay to ask if you actually tried and are stuck at some point - even for homework ;) But in order to be able to really help you, please provide us all the relevant information to do so. A SSCCE (http://www.sscce.org/) would be great.

Comment: But I have a while inside the do loop?

Comment: @ConorDoyle21 That's another while, because it's in a switch-case-block.

Comment: I've changed the while problem and  that error is gone. Now I'm getting multiple 'cannot find symbol errors' ? But all variables have been initialized ?

Comment: @ConorDoyle21 if you are referring to my answer add comment below it. Note that `variable` and `anotherVariable` are fictional names you have to change insides of `while` to desired boolean expression

Comment: @Ziker Yeah I've changed that to what you wrote and I'm just getting cannot find symbols errors. I think its best if I just start from scratch ?

Comment: On which line do you get your error?

Comment: I suupose compiler is complaining about this line `while(variable!=anotherVariable);` you have to chenge it. Think about it this way. How many times do you want to run code between `do{` and `}while()` . Or another way what condition you want to be satisfied in the end of the loop ?

Answer (score 2):

If you use keyword `do{` you have to include `while` keyword to define until when the code specified between `do{` and `while` should do stuff

Solution is include `while` condition like this

```
do{
//do your stuff here... switch etc.

}while(condition) //condition must return boolean value or be boolean expression
```

I see your `while there` so the error is maybe wrong `{` or `}` placement

EDIT:

I copy pasted your code in Netbeans and yes your problem is that your `do{}` is missing `while` statement

Heres your working code with added while

```
public static void main(String[] args)

{   
    int choice;
    int index;
    String name = " ";
    int goals;
    int points;
    int noofthings;
    int location;
    Footballer tempObject;
    String search = "";
    int step;

    noofthings = 0;

    do{
            choice = menu();

            switch(choice)
        {
                    case 1 :
                {
                    step = 0;
                    System.out.print("Enter a name ");
                    name = EasyIn.getString();

                    while((step < noofthings) && !(names[step].getName().equals(name)))
                        {
                            step++;
                        }
                    if(step < noofthings)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Name already exists, choose another ");
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Enter amount of goals ");
                            goals = EasyIn.getInt();
                            System.out.println("Enter amount of points ");
                            points = EasyIn.getInt();
                            tempObject = new Footballer(name, goals, points);
                            location = findPlace(names, tempObject, noofthings);
                            noofthings = addOne(names, location, tempObject, noofthings);
                        }
                }
        }
    }while(variable!=anotherVariable); //added this line
}
```